# Stop charging battery at 100% and vice-versa

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, battery, power-management

Is there any way software / script through which i can stop charging battery when it 100% and vice-versa?

I am not exactly sure how to put in words but ubuntu must be identifying when the power cable is plugged in or not, so, i was wondering if there is any way to *fool* the OS to cut off power when battery is charged to 100%....this off-course requires to identify 2 things

- figuring out how ubuntu identifies connectivity of power plug
- Associate this to the `%` of battery charged after figuring out `%` charged

Does someone has any idea about it?

Comment: (Why) do you see any specific need to actually control this yourself? I’d say this should be built-in on a hardware level already … protection against battery overcharging should be a pretty standard thing nowadays.

Comment: one of the reasons is that if battery is charged 100% but still keeps on getting power then it reduces the battery life and second reason is that my machine doesn't have inbuilt power cut-off feature!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way software / script through which i can stop charging battery when it 100% and vice-versa?

Your laptop's hardware does that for you; if it didn't, the accumulator cells would get hot and possibly catch on fire regularly.

In fact, this functionality is so crucial to your computer's integrity that you can't control it using software (normally; [there might be people who would crack firmware to do exactly that](http://media.ccc.de/browse/congress/2014/31c3_-_6129_-_en_-_saal_2_-_201412282030_-_attacks_on_uefi_security_inspired_by_darth_venamis_s_misery_and_speed_racer_-_rafal_wojtczuk_-_corey_kallenberg.html) -- destroy an opponent's hardware).

If you want to figure out how information like that can be processed, have a look at a [tool called upower](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal).

If you want to work with that information in your own program: Batterystate is available via sysFS in `/sys/class/power_supply/`; look at `BATn`, especially `charge_now` and `charge_full`. These contain numbers (encoded as normal strings).

Comment: This is a good info, but not a satisfying answer, because the reason why you want to do this is to set longer time for battery NOT to be charged - e.g. "*Stop charging at 100%, start at 85%...*" This is a feature to pro-long battery's life and is very commonly handled by the software. (no crack/hack)